# Git SSH public key denied

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I'm using Bitbucket, and I've setup SSH on Git [as instructed for Linux in Atlassian's documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678) (Ubuntu 13.04)

When I try to clone any project from my Bitbucket account though, I get a public key denied error.

```
omk@home-pc:/var/www/git$ sudo git clone git@bitbucket.org:MyAccount/MyProject.git
Cloning into 'MyProject'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have added the public key to my Bitbucket account.

When I try `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org`, only then does the terminal prompt me to enter my passphrase, and I get my account name as response.

```
omk@home-pc:/var/www/git$ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
logged in as MyUsername.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

Cloning at **$HOME** works fine. The issue is with having to use `sudo` at */var/www/git*. Is there any way I should change the permissions to avoid using `sudo`?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is it possible to clone into your home directory without using sudo?

Comment: Nope. Gives me this - fatal: could not create work tree dir 'easydial'.: Permission denied

Comment: Did you try to clone to $HOME, or /var/www/git? (you probably have permission to write to the first, but not to the last.)

Comment: Cloning at $HOME works. Any way I can set permissions to /var/www/git to not use sudo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `ssh-add $keyfile` to add your private key to the agent.

Then use `ssh-add -L` to display the public key for that key. - Verify it matches the one added to your bitbucket account.

Now trying to ssh to bitbucket should result login via key, i.e. *no* password is needed.

Also `git clone` over ssh should work now.

Using `sudo` is probably no good idea. It will most certainly both cut the connection to your agent and change $HOME/.ssh, hence a ssh started by sudo will not be able to use your key.
You can use `sudo -E` to preserve your environment. In this case the key should still work.

Comment: Still the same error. But I see 2 keys on ssh-add -L now. The same key basically. One ends with /home/omk/.ssh/id_rsa and the other with omk@home-pc.

Comment: Any way I could avoid using sudo. I am sensing that is the issue.

Comment: Just found. Using clone on $HOME works fine. Any way I can change the permissions for /var/www/

Comment: Either use `chown` on /var/www/git, or use `sudo -E`. - Depending on, what you are planning to do with the repository.

Comment: Did a cd ; sudo cp .ssh/id_* /root/.ssh/ to move my keys to root. Worked! Thanks :)

Comment: When I run: ssh-add -L, it lists multiple keys.  How which one should I be verifying with BitBucket??

Comment: If your agent knows about multiple keys, you can use any of them. Maybe you should find out where the second key comes from. Probably your desktop environment added a key from `~/.ssh/`.

Comment: You saved my life, thank you! `-E` option made my day.

Answer (score 0):

Add yourself to the group that has access to `/var/www/git`.

Answer (score -2):

I had similar problem and I solved like that: First, I enabled passwd auth then added public key and then disables passwd auth again. I know this is not exactly your problem but I wanted to share my experience.

Comment: Chill :) Just wanted to tell my story.

Comment: Please see: [How to write good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)