# Composer with git SSH stopped working randomly

Tags: git, ssh, composer-php, bitbucket

So, I've been using composer to manage my git repos (on bitbucket) and now, out of the blue composer complains about me not having access to my repos :S

I haven't done anything in particular. But I went ahead and generated a new key using `ssh-keygen`, copied the public key and added it to my bitbucket account.

So I tried `sudo composer update` again, and it still complains:

```
Failed to update git@bitbucket.org:afflicto/event.git, package information from this repository may be outdated (Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
error: Could not fetch origin
)
```

What could be wrong?

#### Update

I just pushed to one of my git repos, and it works fine. So it seems the SSH Key is setup correctly but Composer is doing something strange.

#### Update 2

It seems that running `composer update` as `sudo` (i.e `sudo composer update`) will not use *your* ssh keys... so I have to add my SSH keys to the root user I suppose? :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in this [BitBucket thread](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/3292/permission-denied-publickey):

> By using `sudo ssh` will look for `root`'s keys, not yours in `/home/username/.ssh/`.
>   You probably shouldn't be running git with sudo.
>
> But if you really need to, generate some new keys under the `root` account and upload those to Bitbucket.

Or you can try `sudo -E`, to preserve your environment, as mentioned in "[Git SSH public key denied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18470910/6309)".

Comment: I ended up creating an ssh key for root as well yeah. `sudo -E` though, that's neat!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a 2nd ssh key and needed to add it as an identity in ssh-agent

1. eval $(ssh-agent -s)
2. ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_ssh_private_key

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that my SSH keys had permission 0777 so composer ignored them. I discovered it by running in verbose mode (`composer update   -vvv`)